# Force FileOutputStream to write files do hdd

Tags: java, out-of-memory, java-io, fileoutputstream

I hava a program:

```
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+table1);
while(res.next()){
    String path = "C:/data/"+table+"/"+fileName;
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
    byte[] fileBytes = res.getBytes(columnIndex);
    fos.write(fileBytes);
    fos.flush();
}
```

This program reads binary data from database and exports as files. I would expect it to export each file at a time, but it doesn't. All files are accumulated in memory and saved at the very end. 
The result is OutOfMemoryError. I've just learned flush doesn't guarantee writing to hdd. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Try to close `fos`. Or use try with resource statement.

Comment: Any time you have an exception, you need to include its entire stack trace in your question.

Comment: fos.close() also fails, but I will try Thread.sleep()

Comment: OutOfMemoryError doesn't have much to do with file I/O, you should try to solve that first. A likely candidate  for this OOME to happen is the line `byte[] fileBytes = res.getBytes(columnIndex);`. Maybe you just have a very large BLOB and you need to allocate more heap to your JVM with -Xmx